# List of facilities

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have a basic page called facilities. I would like to list facilities on that page. For example I want to have bank of Ireland and a picture and description then right under that I would like to have Gym and a picture and a description and so on. I would like users to be able to comment on them too.

I tried so many ways but I don't know how to do it. I tried to do it by creating a content type and I can get one to display on the page but then I can't figure out how to display another one right under it on the exact same page.

I also tried doing it with views but it didn't work for me either

Any help be great. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to relate your content models with reference fields. From there you can use Views to create content displays of these references nodes.

Here is a good writeup on it: https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/making-sense-drupal-views-relationships-and-entity-references

For Drupal 7 you will want to grab this module: [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference). Add this new field on the content types you want to add references to, and configure the field. From here, you can either use entity view modes and field formatter displays, or the more popular method is [using Views to relate and display referenced entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004).

Comment: Updated. The linked doc page on drupal.org ought to get you up and running.